# How to show cache image in listview

Tags: android, listview, caching

I m working on an android app which caches images for articles to be shown in webview in following format: "article-id"+"md5 of image url". Now I'm trying to use same cached image in list view. In listView Adapter I m using Holder as follows:

```
    if (view.getTag() == null) {
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        holder.dateTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
        holder.starImgView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.icon);
        view.setTag(holder);
    }

    final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    holder.titleTextView.setText(cursor.getString(mTitlePos));
    holder.starImgView.setImageResource(favorite ? R.drawable.dimmed_rating_important : R.drawable.dimmed_rating_not_important);
    holder.dateTextView.setText(new StringBuilder(feedName).append(Constants.COMMA_SPACE).append(StringUtils.getDateTimeString(cursor.getLong(mDatePos))));
```

I tried a lot, I'm only able to retrieve name of first image of the article from the cache directory but i don't know how to place it in the list view.
I hope someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well , I can't quite get your point properly but I think that you want to display images which are parsed from urls into a list view . if this is your problem then there's an easy solution . first of all you can make your own classes for this (image loader class Google it up) or you can use the open source Picasso library (yes , it does cache images ) very simple to use .

Google that too.

A simple structure :

```
Get view {
Image view a ;
String URL;
Piccaso.into(a).from(URL)
```

}
Something like this but its not this , go ahead to there page and check it out just google picasso library.

:D hope I helped u ( tough to type on mobile)

Comment: I m really sorry if i had made confusions with question. I mean to say i don't want to show them from some url.. i mean to say i have already got images cached in cache directory, i want to use those images into listview. I hope you have got my point

Comment: got it , but isn't this a difficult way of doing things ... ill try searching an answer for you .

Comment: I was trying to do this way because i don't want to increase cache size by downloading lots of images..